# Building BIRT with PDE

Tags: ant, build, eclipse-rcp, product, headless

I'm trying to build BIRT 2.5.2 from source to fix some bugs (I know about BIRT 2.6 but not all of our customers are on BIRT 2.6, yet).

I downloaded the BIRT 2.5.2 source ZIP and I found a couple of product files in there. I unpacked the sources, copied features and plugins to a build directory. Now I run this build.xml:

```
<target name="pde-build">
    <java classname="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main" fork="true" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="-application" />
        <arg value="org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner" />
        <arg value="-buildfile" />
        <arg value="${eclipseLocation}/plugins/org.eclipse.pde.build_${pdeBuildPluginVersion}/scripts/productBuild/productBuild.xml" />
        <arg value="-Dtimestamp=${timestamp}" />
        <arg value="-verbose" />
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${eclipseLocation}/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_${equinoxLauncherPluginVersion}.jar" />
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
```

But I get this error:

```
eclipse-3.5.2/plugins/org.eclipse.pde.build_3.5.2.R35x_20100114/scripts/productBuild/productBuild.xml:64:
Unable to find element: /org.eclipse.birt.report.engine/ReportEngineSDK.product
```

In my build.properties, I say:

```
product=/org.eclipse.birt.report.engine/ReportEngineSDK.product
```

and there is a file `build/plugins/org.eclipse.birt.report.engine/ReportEngineSDK.product`

My guess is that Eclipse has a search path of some kind to locate the product file.

What do I have to specify in the build.xml/.properties to make the `productBuild.xml` pick up the product file?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I need the full path to the `.product` file in the property `product`.

In addition, the `ReportEngineSDK.product` is outdated. Use `.../features/org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature/product/BIRT.product` instead.